# window.getSelection add class to selection with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, execcommand

I want to select an image and a add a class name to the selection. using `window.getSelection`.

```
function addClassName() {
     var sel = window.getSelection();
     //what goes here???
}


<input type='button' onclick='addClassName();' value='addClassName'/>
```

Comment: are the image(s) preloaded or you are fetching the image on click through ajax?

Comment: @3nigma: window.getSelection buddy , window.getSelection

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To add class to selection, you need to wrap it with `<span>` other wise it will not work. Here's the solution.

```
    function addClassToSelection(){
    var sel = window.getSelection ? window.getSelection() : document.selection.createRange(); // FF : IE
    if(sel.getRangeAt){ // thats for FF
    var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
    var newNode = document.createElement("span");
    newNode.setAttribute('class', 'someclass');
    range.surroundContents(newNode);
    } else { //and thats for IE7
    sel.pasteHTML('<span class="someclass">'+sel.htmlText+'</span>');

    }
    }
```

This should guide you in the proper direction. Modify it as you see fit.

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/wP8w9/2/

Comment: Yes, it should be in the code, looks like i missed it. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

`$(sel).find('img').addClass('myClass');`

This will take the selection, turn it into a jQuery object, find the image, and add a class to it.

I have not tested this.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use javascript you can do:

```
function addClassName() {
     $('img').addClass('newClass') // adds the class 'newClass' to all image objects
}


<input type='button' onclick='addClassName();' value='addClassName'/>
```

you can use any selector aside from 'img' in that function as well

Comment: @maniator: No, only the "selected" image. I mentioned window.getSelection

Comment: what do you mean the 'selected' image?

Comment: @maniator: I suppose you are not familiar with DOM manipulation. https://developer.mozilla.org/Special:Tags?tag=DOM&language=en

Comment: i am familiar with DOM. thank you. but i dont see how you can 'select' an image. it is not an input element

Comment: @maniator you can highlight text or other page content and get the selection with js.

Comment: ok then @mathletics answer combined with mine might work then

Comment: dany is taking about highlighting an image with the mouse just as you would click and drag over the text to heighlight it. The selection term can be confusing.

Answer (score 0):

```
var sel= window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);

$(sel).addClass("someClass");
```

`window.getSelection()` will give you the selection, but not the current (or highlighted) selection. You need to use the selection's getRangeAt method for that

Answer (score 0):

To get the class of selected text

```
window.getSelection().baseNode.parentElement.className
```